Origin of starting letter ´X´ in placenames
I recently noted several French placenames starting with an X in the Vosges, such as Xertigny and Xonrupt-Longemer. Also, the X in Uxegney strikes me as 'Unfrench'. I am curious about the origin of these placenames.

Another example: Xouaxange.

Those are terms taken from Lorrain, with the spelling usually already established in medieval Latin.
Eastern oïl languages, unlike central ones like French, preserved the palatalised /s/ of late Latin as /ʃ/ ("sh"), /x/ (the German ach-laut) or /h/. That sound was distinct (at least at the time) from the affricate /tʃ/ that came to be spelled "ch" in French, and thus often developed its own spelling in the local scriptas.
"X" was one of those, and in those place names it's in fact supposed to be pronounced /ʃ/ though spelling pronunciation often does lead to pronunciations like /ks/.
It's directly comparable to the "xh" found in Eastern Belgium, in place or people names like Droixhe or Xhoris, although there the intended pronunciation in French is often /h/ or nothing.

I'm being told that in Xouaxange, the two "x" are not pronounced the same. It sounds like "Souagzange" (I can't write in phonetic alphabet).

@Frank Il est en effet fort possible que le deuxième X représente un son plus traditionnel pour cette lettre, vu que la plus ancienne graphie de 1240 est Schwekesingen. La prononciation a aussi certainement évolué au cours des siècles puisqu'un [s] s'est substitué au [χ] original et, plus courant, [gz] à [ks].

I would be very disappointed if the right pronounciation suppressed the innuendo in Sexey-aux-Forges. Don't care about the 2nd x, note.
